# Adjusting the scope of the callback function of onclick

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I'm trying to solve a programming exercise in which there are several bugs to be fixed. Ultimately, it is supposed to represent an animation with a grid of cells where at each time step, if a cell has exactly three neighbors which are alive (each cell has 8 neighbors), it 'comes to life', and if it has less than 2 or more than 3 neighbors, it 'dies' (where the neighbors 'wrap around' the grid). The initial script is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Board;
var xsize = 10;
var ysize = 10;

var dead = 0;
var alive = 1;

function Neighbors(Board, x, y)
{
    var n = 0
    for(dx=-1;dx < 1; ++dx)
        for(dy=-1;dy < 1; ++dy)
        {
            var ax = x+dx;
            var ay = y+dy;
            if(Board[ax][ay]==alive) ++n;
        }
    return n;
}

function Kill(Board,x,y)
{
    if(Board[x][y] == alive)
        Board[x][y] = dead;
}

function MakeLive(Board,x,y)
{
    if(Board[x][y] == dead)
        Board[x][y] = alive;
}

function NextStep(Board)
{
    for(var x = 0; x <= xsize; ++x)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y <= ysize; ++x)
        {
            n = Neighbors(Board,x,y);
            if(n=3) MakeLive(Board,x,y);
            if((n<2)||(n>3)) Kill(Board,x,y);
        }
    }
}

function DrawBoard(Board)
{
    var Text = "";
    for(var y = 0; y < ysize; ++y)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < xsize; ++x)
            Text += Board[x][y]==alive ? "o":"_";
        Text += "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = Text;
}

function Main()
{
    // *** Change this variable to choose a different baord setup from below
    var BoardSetup = "blinker";

    Board = new Array(xsize);
    for(var x = 0; x < xsize; ++x)
    {
        Board[x] = new Array(ysize);
        for(var y = 0; y < ysize; ++y)
            Board[x][y] = 0;
    }

    if(BoardSetup == "blinker")
    {
        Board[1][0] = 1;
        Board[1][1] = 1;
        Board[1][2] = 1;
    }
    else if(BoardSetup == "glider")
    {
        Board[2][0] = 1;
        Board[2][1] = 1;
        Board[2][2] = 1;
        Board[1][2] = 1;
        Board[0][1] = 1;
    }
    else if(BoardSetup == "flower")
    {
        Board[4][6] = 1;
        Board[5][6] = 1;
        Board[6][6] = 1;
        Board[7][6] = 1;
        Board[8][6] = 1;
        Board[9][6] = 1;
        Board[10][6] = 1;
        Board[4][7] = 1;
        Board[6][7] = 1;
        Board[8][7] = 1;
        Board[10][7] = 1;
        Board[4][8] = 1;
        Board[5][8] = 1;
        Board[6][8] = 1;
        Board[7][8] = 1;
        Board[8][8] = 1;
        Board[9][8] = 1;
        Board[10][8] = 1;
    }

    DrawBoard(Board);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Main()">
<div id="board">
</div>
<a href="#IGoNowhere" onclick="NextStep(Board);DrawBoard(Board);">Next -></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if I press the 'Next' button, in the console I see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
    at Neighbors (life_broken__281_29.html:19)
    at Function.NextStep (life_broken__281_29.html:42)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (life_broken__281_29.html:117)
Neighbors @ life_broken__281_29.html:19
NextStep @ life_broken__281_29.html:42
onclick @ life_broken__281_29.html:117
```

The problem, I believe, is that the `Board` is defined in the `Main()` function, which is not in the scope of the `onclick` callback function.

My initial approach was to move the initialization of the `Board` outside of the `Main()` function, making it a global variable, and removing `Board` from all function calls. This does not seem like an elegant approach, however. Instead, I tried using [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) as follows:

```
<a href="#IGoNowhere" onclick="NextStep.call(Main, Board); DrawBoard.call(Main, Board);">Next -></a>
```

Further, I implemented a `wrapAround` function to avoid the indices going out of bounds:

```
function Neighbors(Board, x, y)
{
    var n = 0
    for(dx=-1;dx < 1; ++dx)
        for(dy=-1;dy < 1; ++dy)
        {
            var ax = x+dx;
            var ay = y+dy;
            ax = wrapAround(ax, xsize);
            ay = wrapAround(ay, ysize);
            if(Board[ax][ay]==alive) ++n;
        }
    return n;
}

function wrapAround(coordinate, size) {
    var result = coordinate % size;
    if (result < 0) {
        result += size;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, now I get a new error:

```
life_broken__281_29.html:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at MakeLive (life_broken__281_29.html:42)
    at Function.NextStep (life_broken__281_29.html:53)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (life_broken__281_29.html:127)
```

Apparently, the `Neighbors` function is now not raising any errors, but the next function in `NextStep`, `MakeLive`, is. This I don't understand however because they are both defined at the same 'level' and have similar invocations in `NextStep`. Can anyone explain what the issue is here?

**Update**

Indeed `Board` is declared in the global scope, so there was no need for `Function.prototype.call()`. (I'm used to Python where declaration and definition are always in the same place). I also changed the Boolean expression to `(x === 3)`.

However, for some reason `x` is still going up to `10` even if I replace the `<=` by a `<`. Here is the updated code, with a `console.log` statement for debugging:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Board;
var xsize = 10;
var ysize = 10;

var dead = 0;
var alive = 1;

function Neighbors(Board, x, y)
{
    var n = 0
    for(dx=-1;dx < 1; ++dx)
        for(dy=-1;dy < 1; ++dy)
        {
            var ax = x+dx;
            var ay = y+dy;
            ax = wrapAround(ax, xsize);
            ay = wrapAround(ay, ysize);
            if(Board[ax][ay]==alive) ++n;
        }
    return n;
}

function wrapAround(coordinate, size) {
    var result = coordinate % size;
    if (result < 0) {
        result += size;
    }
    return result;
}

function Kill(Board, x, y)
{
    if (Board[x][y] == alive)
        Board[x][y] = dead;
}

function MakeLive(Board, x, y)
{
    if (Board[x][y] == dead)
        Board[x][y] = alive;
}

function NextStep(Board)
{
    for(var x = 0; x < xsize; ++x)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < ysize; ++x)
        {
            n = Neighbors(Board,x,y);
            console.log("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", n = " + n);
            if (n===3) MakeLive(Board,x,y);
            if ((n<2)||(n>3)) Kill(Board,x,y);
        }
    }
}

function DrawBoard(Board)
{
    var Text = "";
    for(var y = 0; y < ysize; ++y)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < xsize; ++x)
            Text += Board[x][y]==alive ? "o":"_";
        Text += "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = Text;
}

function Main()
{
    // *** Change this variable to choose a different baord setup from below
    var BoardSetup = "blinker";

    Board = new Array(xsize);
    for(var x = 0; x < xsize; ++x)
    {
        Board[x] = new Array(ysize);
        for(var y = 0; y < ysize; ++y)
            Board[x][y] = 0;
    }

    if(BoardSetup == "blinker")
    {
        Board[1][0] = 1;
        Board[1][1] = 1;
        Board[1][2] = 1;
    }
    else if(BoardSetup == "glider")
    {
        Board[2][0] = 1;
        Board[2][1] = 1;
        Board[2][2] = 1;
        Board[1][2] = 1;
        Board[0][1] = 1;
    }
    else if(BoardSetup == "flower")
    {
        Board[4][6] = 1;
        Board[5][6] = 1;
        Board[6][6] = 1;
        Board[7][6] = 1;
        Board[8][6] = 1;
        Board[9][6] = 1;
        Board[10][6] = 1;
        Board[4][7] = 1;
        Board[6][7] = 1;
        Board[8][7] = 1;
        Board[10][7] = 1;
        Board[4][8] = 1;
        Board[5][8] = 1;
        Board[6][8] = 1;
        Board[7][8] = 1;
        Board[8][8] = 1;
        Board[9][8] = 1;
        Board[10][8] = 1;
    }

    DrawBoard(Board);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Main()">
<div id="board">
</div>
<a href="#IGoNowhere" onclick="NextStep(Board); DrawBoard(Board);">Next -></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the result of the console when I click 'Next':

```
x = 0, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 1, y = 0, n = 1
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 2, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 3, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 4, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 5, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 6, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 7, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 8, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 9, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:53 x = 10, y = 0, n = 0
life_broken__281_29.html:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Kill (life_broken__281_29.html:36)
    at NextStep (life_broken__281_29.html:55)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (life_broken__281_29.html:128)
```

I'm a bit nonplussed why this is happening because a simple `for` loop in this fashion does work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    console.log("i = " + i);
}
VM158:2 i = 0
VM158:2 i = 1
VM158:2 i = 2
VM158:2 i = 3
VM158:2 i = 4
VM158:2 i = 5
VM158:2 i = 6
VM158:2 i = 7
VM158:2 i = 8
VM158:2 i = 9
undefined
```

Is the console somehow using a cached version of the old code? (I'm using the Live Preview in Brackets).

**Update 2**

This is because I should use a post-increment instead of a pre-increment (cf. http://jsforallof.us/2014/07/10/pre-increment-vs-post-increment/). Changing the `++x` to `x++` solved the problem.

Comment: `Board` is a global variable. `Main()` assigns to it, it doesn't declare it locally.

Comment: The classic [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with variable scope. `Board` is a global variable, so it's accessible to any function.

Your original problem was because you were accessing outside the `Board` array when `x = 0` and `dx = -1`, and you fixed that with your `wrapAround()` function.

The next problem is that your loops in `NextStep` go too far. The row indexes go from `0` to `xsize-1` and the columns go from `0` to `ysize-1`. But the loop there uses `x <= xsize` and `y <= ysize`, so it will try to access `Board[xsize]`, which doesn't exist. Change those `<=` to `<`, just like the loop in `Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

`if(n=3) MakeLive(Board,x,y);`, your `n = 3` should be `n === 3`, I'm sure you don't want to assign `3` to `n` which would cause a `truthy` value, which will call `MakeLive(Board,x,y);` every time.

Also, in `NextStep` you have  your `x` and `y` go all the way up to `xsize` and `ysize` (`<=`) whereas everywhere else you use `<`, think that causes your `undefined` value in `Board[x]`